# Find by _id in mongodb in a node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using a node.js and mongodb, and I'm trying get item by _id

```
  const id = "57bb26e5b2f56d2d47f5e092";
  const tree = db.collection('tree');
  var obj_id = new ObjectID(id);
  const node = tree.findOne({ _id: obj_id });
```

Result of this query is empty, when i'm trying make that query on mlab.com  i get same result, only mongo-shell was return what i expected.

I'm trying that variants:

1. `var obj_id = ObjectId(id);`
2. `var obj_id = "57bb26e5b2f56d2d47f5e092"`

Still the same

What i do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? What's the value of `node`? (`tree.findOne` should return a promise, or alternatively, you should give it a callback function.)

Answer (score 2):

You will need a callback on your `findOne` method per the documentation here:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne

If you are using async/await you will need to add the `await` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, that help, in my case i forgot await
`const node = await tree.findOne({ _id: obj_id });`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Updated answer for this case.